# Консоль выводит ошибку о несуществующей функции, хотя я написал ее

Tags: javascript, dom

Для удаления заметок в своем приложении я поставил svg-иконку, имеющая атрибут `onclick = "delete_note();"`

Но выводится ошибка:

```
ReferenceError: delete_note is not defined
at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick
```

Весьма странно, ведь я создал функцию с данным названием

```
function add_note(){
        section = document.getElementById("all_notes");
        var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'); 
        var date = document.querySelector('input');
        
        save_note = document.createElement("div");
        save_note.className = "note";
        section.appendChild(save_note);
        
        var text_of_note = document.createElement("div");
        text_of_note.className = "text_of_note";
        
        var date_of_note = document.createElement("p");
        date_of_note.className = "date_of_note";

        var text_for_text_of_note = document.createTextNode(textarea.value);           
        text_of_note.appendChild(text_for_text_of_note);
        
        var date_for_date_of_note = document.createTextNode(date.value);
        date_of_note.appendChild(date_for_date_of_note);

        function delete_note(){
            section.removeChild(note);
        }
        
        var delete_icon = document.createElement("svg");
        delete_icon.className = "delete_icon";
        delete_icon.setAttribute("onclick", "delete_note();");

        save_note.appendChild(text_of_note);
        save_note.appendChild(date_of_note);
        text_of_note.appendChild(delete_icon);
    }
```

Полный HTML(в section c id=all_notes я скидываю все добавленное)

```
<body>
<div class="header_of_page">
    <div class="title_page">Заметки и Напоминания</div>
    <div class="subtitle">Создавай новые идеи и ставь новые задачи</div>
</div>
<section class="create_note">
    <div class="box">
        <p class="input_intro">Ввод текста</p>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <p class="input_intro">Добавление даты</p>
        <input type="date">
        <div class="buttons">  
            <div class="add-btn" onclick="add_note();">Добавить Заметку</div>
            <div class="clear-btn">Очистить все</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="notes_lists" id="all_notes">
</section>
```

Comment: У вас функция называется add_note, а в onclick delete_note

Comment: Вынесите  function delete_note(){
            section.removeChild(note);
        } из функции add note

Comment: @AzizUmarov а как это должно влиять?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, функции используемые в inline обработчиках должны быть глобальными

Comment: @Grundy надо в `window.` добавить :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, как вариант :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю другое решение проблемы. Если хочется использовать функцию в функции. Возможно решит:

```
delete_icon.addEventListener('click', () => { delete_note(); });
//delete_icon.setAttribute("onclick", "delete_note;");
```

Comment: Благодарю, извините что поздно ответил.Но работает только один раз, если пользователь добавит еще заметки, то они функция не будет действовать, выдавая такую ошибку Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at delete_note

Comment: @НарутоУзумаки возможно вам нужно передавать `note` в слушателя и в функции уже ею работать `delete_icon.addEventListener('click', () => { delete_note(note); });` и `delete_note(note)`. Но в текущем вашем коде я не вижу  вообще переменной `note`. И без html сложно что-то сказать

Comment: упс, на месте note должен стоять save_note

Answer (score -3):

Вижу, вы не понимаете область видимости. Если просто, "то, что находится в фигурных скобках, видно только внутри этих фигурных скобок". Ваша функция `delete_note` объявляется внутри функции `add_note`. Поэтому вашу `delete_note` не видно снаружи. Ваш html и тег `script` находимся в глобальной области видимости (ваша страница). Просто объявите `delete_note` снаружи `add_note`. Если вам нужно чтобы у этих функций были общие переменные, их тоже вынесите в глобальную область,
например вот так:

```
let lastNote = null; 
let section = $('#all_notes')
function add_note(){
    lastNote = someValue;
    …
}

function delete_note(){
    section.removeChild(lastNote); 
    …
}
```

Если совсем не хотите менять существующий код, занесите `delete_note` в `window`:

```
window.delete_note = function delete_note(){…}
```